# Why is StopAsync called twice when stopping IHost?

Tags: c#, .net, discord.net

I am working on a Discord bot using Discord.Net and Discord.Addons.Hosting packages. For some reason, when I call IHost.StopAsync() method, all StopAsync methods in my IHostedServices are called twice.

Here is one of the StopAsync methods:

```cs
public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) 
{
    Logger.LogInformation("Client [{clientId}] is stopped.", Client.CurrentUser.Id);
    
    return base.StopAsync(stoppingToken);
}
```

I shutdown my bot using a command !shutdown:

```cs
[Command("shutdown")]
[RequireUserPermission(GuildPermission.Administrator, Group = "Permission")]
[RequireOwner(Group = "Permission")]
public async Task Stop() 
{
    await _host.StopAsync();
}
```

Here are the logs when I try to shut down the bot:

```
[11:08:41 INF] Application is shutting down...
[11:08:46 INF] Client [1007213990742610001] is stopped.
[11:08:46 INF] Client [1007213990742610001] is stopped.
[11:08:46 INF] Discord.NET hosted service is stopping
[11:08:46 INF] Discord.NET hosted service is stopping
[11:08:46 INF] Gateway: Disconnecting
```

Comment: Are you starting (`StartAsync`) or running (`RunAsync`) the host?

Comment: @StephenCleary I am using RunAsync()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`RunAsync` itself calls `StopAsync`](https://andrewlock.net/introducing-ihostlifetime-and-untangling-the-generic-host-startup-interactions/). If you want to stop the host from within the host, then call [`IHostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime.stopapplication?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#microsoft-extensions-hosting-ihostapplicationlifetime-stopapplication) instead of `IHost.StopAsync()`.